# Vb.Net formatting datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, format

I have been browsing sample pictures for some form designs and found this picture
[image]

This picture looks like a datagridview with textbox and comobobx columns. I am ok with how to add a combobx to a datagridview. How can I format a datagridview to have the exact same look?

Comment: [Adding a button to DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085930/add-button-column-in-a-databound-datagridview).. As far as everything else is concerned, the Form BackColor seems to be Grey, and the Headings seem to have been changed. Other than that, there isn't much else that could have been done, if this is indeed even a SS of a DataGridView. Color schemes can be applied at run time, same with the formatting. The only thing that leads me to believe this isn't a DGV is the red 'X' button to the right of the Date column.

Comment: But you can add a button to the datagridview the same way to add combobox! and the headings can be changed in many ways. So you think this is not a datagridview?

Comment: Just the column spacing and that button throw me off a little bit. I'm sure there is someone out there with more experience than I, however if I had to guess I would assume it isn't a DataGridView. You can make yours look very similar though. You stated you are 'ok' with the combobox, so all that leaves is adding a button, so check the link I posted in my first comment, and see what you can come up with! Play around a bit!

Comment: I see, but some how I feel that this is a datagridview with the padding and other properties set to a specific values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a DataGridView, As far as i know i thinks its access form where as textbox , combobox controls are placed in Details sections and it will repeated for each row in query behind the access form.

If you want to use a DataGridView with combo boxes please refer following questions
[vb.net / DataGridView / ComboBoxCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247500/vb-net-datagridview-comboboxcell)